# TFS, get username by GUID

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, tfs-sdk

TFS 2015 update 2.

Some TFS REST endpoints (e. g. release details) return a reference to a user as a combination of display name and a GUID.

How can I retrieve the Windows username for the said user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could not directly use Rest API to get what you need on TFS 2015 update 2.

You have to use Client API such as [IIdentityManagementService.ReadIdentity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff731745%28v=vs.120%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)  
method to achieve it.

```
ConfigurationServer.GetService<IIdentityManagementService>().ReadIdentities(guid, ....)
```

For more details please refer this [blog](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/2009/01/14/tfs-api-part-4-get-tfs-user-list-mail-sid-account-domain/) which can give you help.